# Why does (myMC.myArray = myOtherMC.myOtherArray;) cause any changes to myMC.myArray to also change myOtherMC.myOtherArray?

Tags: actionscript-3

```
var myArray:Array = new Array();
var myMC:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
myMC.myArray = myArray;
trace(myMC.myArray[10]);               //Output: undefined
var newMC:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
newMC.myOtherArray = myMC.myArray;
newMC.myOtherArray[10] = [];
newMC.myOtherArray[10][0] = 100;
trace(myMC.myArray[10]);               //Output: 100
```

Why does that happen, and is there any way to avoid it?

EDIT:

Found a function that can clone associative arrays [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7ee7.html).

Here is the function (from the above link):

```
function clone(source:Object):* 
{ 
    var myBA:ByteArray = new ByteArray(); 
    myBA.writeObject(source); 
    myBA.position = 0; 
    return(myBA.readObject()); 
}
```

Does making the function return type "*" mean that it can be any type? or is it something specific to objects/arrays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you have passed a reference of the original array to the new clip. Arrays, as objects, are not primitives and therefore will always be referenced.

If you would like to clone an array, keeping the original intact, use this method:

```
var b:Array = a.concat();
```

b will be a new array. a can modified without changing b.

Comment: What if it is an associative array?

Comment: @JaxBantam An [**associative array**](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7eea.html) is an array that contain named elements (keys: "a", "foo", "score", ...) instead of numbered elements (index : 0, 1, 2, ...).

Comment: The Object instance can serve as an associative array, and usually it's best to manually copy each property to a new object.

Comment: You could store objects into arrays, and do something like: trace(myArray[1][keyValue])